# How long can we iterate circumcenters?

Tags: geometry, set-theory, euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

Given a triangle $T$, we can define a transfinite sequence $(\mathsf{CS}_\alpha(T))_{\alpha\in\mathsf{Ord}}$ of "circum*sets*" as follows:

- $\mathsf{CS}_0(T)=T$,
- $\mathsf{CS}_{\alpha+1}(T)=\mathsf{CS}_\alpha(T)$ $\cup $ the set of all circumcenters of nondegenerate triangles with vertices in $\mathsf{CS}_\alpha(T)$, and
- $\mathsf{CS}_\lambda(T)=cl(\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}\mathsf{CS}_\alpha(T))$ for $\lambda$ limit (where $cl(A)$ is the closure of $A$ in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Let the **circum*ordinal*** of $T$, $\mathsf{co(T)}$, be the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\mathsf{CS}_\alpha(T)=\mathsf{CS}_{\alpha+1}(T)$. It's easy to show that $\mathsf{co}(T)<\omega_1$: given points $a,b,c\in \mathsf{CS}_{\omega_1}(T)$ we can find sequences $(a_i)_{i<\omega},(b_i)_{i<\omega},(c_i)_{i<\omega}$ of points in earlier $\mathsf{CS}$-levels converging to $a,b$, and $c$ respectively, but since $\omega_1$ is regular this means that $a,b,c\in\mathsf{CS}_\alpha(T)$ for some $\alpha<\omega_1$.

> Are there arbitrarily large countable circumordinals? More ambitiously, *which* countable ordinals are circumordinals?

(The more ambitious question seems nontrivial even in the finite case.) I have only been able to find a small amount of existing work about iterated circumcenter processes (e.g. [this MO discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28073/iterated-circumcircle) or [this student(!) paper](https://hlma.hanglung.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/dffde8480d93777346529dd820577ccb.pdf)), none of which seems directly related, but I'm not an expert so I could easily be missing something obvious.

Comment: I believe it follows from a problem of Stan Wagon that no finite ordinals are circumordinals. See [my paper extending that result](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/STCTCC.pdf) for the reference (first paragraph).

Comment: @GregMartin Neat! At a quick glance I suspect that the proof of the theorem of that paper in fact shows that $\mathsf{co}(T)=\omega$ always. Does that seem plausible?

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right! I didn't notice the closure operator in your definition (maybe it's not even crucial for this deduction); is it indeed the case that co$(T)=\omega$ follows directly from the statement that every circle-center set is dense in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @GregMartin Actually unless I'm missing something the continuity of the circumcenter-forming process means that this stops being interesting at step $\omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a silly moment: it's easy to show that $\mathsf{co}(T)\le\omega$ always.

Specifically, let $X=\bigcup_{n<\omega}\mathsf{CS}_\alpha(T)$. Then $X$ is "a circle-center set" - the circumcenter of every triangle with vertices in $X$ is itself in $X$. But the map sending a triangle to its circumcenter is appropriately continuous, so in fact the closure of $X$ is also circumcenter-closed. (A bit more rigorously: given noncollinear points $a,b,c\in cl(X)$ we can find sequences $a_i\rightarrow a, b_i\rightarrow b, c_i\rightarrow c$ of points in $X$. Letting $d_i$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle a_ib_ic_i$, we have $d_i\in X$. But the sequence of $d_i$s converges to the circumcenter of $\triangle abc$.)

In the comments above, [Greg Martin mentioned a paper](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Egerg/papers/downloads/STCTCC.pdf) showing that the only closed circle-center set is $\mathbb{R}^2$. Combined with the above this means that $\mathsf{co}(T)=\omega$ for all $T$.